# Загрузка файлов в БД MySQL через форму напрямую

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Вопрос не простой, вопрос с подковыркой.
Был уже на многих сайтах, гуглил - руки уже болят.
Вопрос поставлю четко, и не надо спрашивать "ЗАЧЕМ?".
Итак, нужно, чтобы пользователь сайта мог загрузить файл. При этом этот самый файл должен отправится не абы-куда, а на вечное хранение в БД. Задерживаться на диске ему не нужно(разве только временно, потом удаляется). Помогите, пожалуйста, очень надо.

Comment: вы либо хреново гуглите, либо хреново объясняете - я так и не увидел, в чем трудность. Реализация upload'a файлов ничего сложного не представляет

Comment: А вы отвечать не умеете :)

Comment: Не нужно меня провоцировать на глупый спор. Что я умею, я знаю без вас. А отвечать я предпочитаю на вопросы, в которых человеку нужна помощь, а не на те, где ему лень разбираться самому. Я еще раз вам говорю - ваш вопрос ни малейшей сложности не представляет

Comment: В подтверждение слов @DreamChild, о том что плохо гуглили - [Uploading Files To MySQL Database](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx). А спрашивать вас "ЗАЧЕМ?" не имеет смысла, т.к. вы со временем сами себя спросите, хватаясь за голову: "Зачем же я это сделал?"

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю загружать файлы на сервер Вы умете, дальше присваиваете содержимое файла в переменную и пихаете в поле типа BLOB. создаете дополнительные поля в таблице для типа файла, имени и других параметров.

Но это изврат))))